# Extract text between two tags using regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Let say I have this string which contains html a tag:

```
<a href="abgeordnete-1128-0----w8397.html" class="small_link">Berlin-Treptow-Köpenick</a>
```

How do I use regex in ruby to extract the text of "**Berlin-Treptow-Köpenick**" ?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: You should specify the extraction rule. For example, it appears from the example that it is the text comprised of alphanumeric characters and `'-'` following the character  '>', but the reader cannot determine if that would always be the case. Also, when you give an example, it is helpful to assign all input objects to variables (e.g., str = "<a href...") so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: I know this question is pretty old, but I think its still worth noting:  Your title clearly states that you want to extract text from between 2 tags, but the question does not.  Furthermore, you don't specify what those tags are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
html = '<a href="abgeordnete-1128-0----w8397.html" class="small_link">Berlin-Treptow-Köpenick</a>'

html[/>(.*)</, 1]
#=> "Berlin-Treptow-Köpenick"
```

When your HTML partials are more complex then I recommend using a libraries like [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/):

```
html = '<a href="abgeordnete-1128-0----w8397.html" class="small_link">Berlin-Treptow-Köpenick</a>'

require 'nokogiri'

Nokogiri::HTML(html).text
#=> "Berlin-Treptow-Köpenick"
```

Comment: This is awesome, but looks like a magic :) Could you please provide the docs or some description how it works?

Answer (score 2):

I have made the assumption that the string to be extracted is comprised of alphanumeric characters--including accented letters--and hyphens, and that the string immediately follows the first instance of the character `'>'`.

```
string =
'<a href="abgeordnete-1128-0----w8397.html" class="small_link">Berlin-Treptow-Köpenick</a>'

r = /
    (?<=\>)       # match '>' in a positive lookbehind
    [\p{Alnum}-]+ # match >= 0 alphameric character and hyphens
    /x            # extended or free-spacing mode

string[r] #=> "Berlin-Treptow-Köpenick"
```

Note that `/A-Za-z0-9/` does not match accented characters such as `'ö'`.

Alternatively, one can use the POSIX syntax:

```
r = /(?<=\>)[[[:alnum:]]-]+/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = '<a href="abgeordnete-1128-0----w8397.html" class="small_link">Berlin-Treptow-Köpenick</a>'

string.scan(/<[a][^>]*>(.+?)<\/[a]>/).flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(html)

this base helper return only text

html = `"<a href=\" https://something.com/\"></a><br><strong style=\"color: red;\"><em><del>this</del></em></strong> <strong style=\"color: red;\"><em style=\"color: red;\">works</em></strong"`

and this will be returned *"this works"*